# Assign Elastic IP to VPC EC2 instance on boot

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have a script that uses ec2-associate-address that I have set in a cron job to run on boot. The idea is to use this instance as a spot instance that will automatically get its public IP assigned on boot. However, since it is a VPC instance, it seems like it cannot make outbound requests until the EIP is assigned.

The error I get is:
    Unknown problem connecting to host: 'https://ec2.amazonaws.com'
    Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to ec2.amazonaws.com:443 timed out

What is the easiest way to accomplish this? I know the ID of the EIP, but I obviously will not have the instance ID since it is a spot request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EC2 has an option to auto-associate a random public IP upon instance creation. If you enable that, your instance should be able to issue the API call to associate your EIP.

If you're using the python-based [AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html), you can issue the `--associate-public-ip-address` paramater to do this. If you're not using this tool, you should start doing so, as the java-based command-line tools which you're using will eventually be deprecated.

Comment: Thanks! Relaunching the instance with an auto-IP did the trick!